# No Bluetooth Adapter found Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: bluetooth, 19.04

My Bluetooth adapter suddenly disappeared, and I have been trying to fix it but no luck.

I have tried to enable or start it again but its status is still **inactive**.

```
~$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth

~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
    Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Oct 14 00:33:19 lau-desktop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Oct 14 00:34:27 lau-desktop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Oct 14 00:34:43 lau-desktop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Oct 14 00:37:36 lau-desktop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start the service without a reboot, you should run:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now bluetooth
```

Or:

```
$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

If you simply run `systemctl enable` it will enable the service for the next boot, but it wont start it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i have tried `$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth` many times already, still no luck

Comment: this `$ sudo systemctl enable --now bluetooth` works! thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @laukok, if the answer solved your question, please mark it so with the green tick next to it! Thanks.

Comment: Neither of these work for me any ideas?